# Why is my database not being cleared after each unit test?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, vapor

I am trying to run a tests when no user is created and one can sign up for the first time. The test runs perfectly the first time and passes. The thing is that if I run it a second time, my container is not deleted properly and we end up with a `HTTPStatus.conflict` instead of `.ok`, so the user does already exist.

I am running a Docker container on my MacBook with `docker-compose-testing`, `docker-compose` and `testing.Dockerfile` set.

This error is also triggered when running the test:

`caught error: "server: syntax error at end of input (scanner_yyerror)"`

What is it missing here? Wouldn't `autoRevert()` and `autoMigrate()` clear my database?

```swift
func testSignUpRoute_userDoesNotExistInDatabase_userSignUpAndHTTPStatusIsOk() throws {
  // Configuration in setUp and tearDown.
  var app = Application(.testing)
  defer { app.shutdown() }
  try configure(app)
  try app.autoRevert().wait()
  try app.autoMigrate().wait()
  
  // Given
  let expected: HTTPStatus = .ok
  let headers = [
    "email": "foo@email.com",
    "password": "fooEncrypted"
  ]
  
  // When
  try app.test(.POST, "users/signup") { request in
    try request.content.encode(headers)
  } afterResponse: { response in
    let result = response.status
    
    // Then
    XCTAssertEqual(result, expected, "Response status must be \(expected)")
  }
}
```

This is the order in which my migration happens in the `configure.swift` file:

```swift
public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
  app.migrations.add(UserModelMigration_v1_0_0())
  app.migrations.add(AddressModelMigration_v1_0_0())
}
```

And the this is how I revert all my models. `AddressModel` and `CompanyModel` are `@OptionalChild` of the `UserModel`. It seems like the issue comes from here, but I can not point it out.

```swift
struct UserModelMigration_v1_0_0: Migration {

  func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    database.schema(UserModel.schema)
      .id()
      .field(UserModel.Key.email, .string, .required)
      .field(UserModel.Key.password, .string, .required)
      .unique(on: UserModel.Key.email)
      .create()
  }

  func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    database
      .schema(UserModel.schema)
      .update()
  }
}
```

```swift
struct AddressModelMigration_v1_0_0: Migration {

  func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    database.schema(AddressModel.schema)
      .id()
      .field(AddressModel.Key.streetLineOne, .string, .required)
      .field(AddressModel.Key.city, .string, .required)
      .field(AddressModel.Key.userID, .uuid, .required,
             .references(UserModel.schema, .id,
                         onDelete: .cascade,
                         onUpdate: .cascade))
      .unique(on: AddressModel.Key.userID)
      .create()
  }

  func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    database
      .schema(AddressModel.schema)
      .update()
  }
}
```

This is my `docker-compose-testing.yml` file

```yaml
version: '3'

services:

  testingonlinux:

    depends_on:
      - postgres

    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: testing.Dockerfile

    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=postgres
      - DATABASE_PORT=5434

  postgres:

    image: "postgres"

    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=foo_db_testing
      - POSTGRES_USER=foo_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foo_password
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```yaml
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  db_data:

x-shared_environment: &shared_environment
  LOG_LEVEL: ${LOG_LEVEL:-debug}
  DATABASE_HOST: db
  DATABASE_NAME: vapor_database
  DATABASE_USERNAME: vapor_username
  DATABASE_PASSWORD: vapor_password

services:
  app:
    image: FooServerSide:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    # user: '0' # uncomment to run as root for testing purposes even though Dockerfile defines 'vapor' user.
    command: ["serve", "--env", "production", "--hostname", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8080"]
  migrate:
    image: FooServerSide:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["migrate", "--yes"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
  revert:
    image: FooServerSide:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: ["migrate", "--revert", "--yes"]
    deploy:
      replicas: 0
  db:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
      POSTGRES_USER: vapor_username
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: vapor_password
      POSTGRES_DB: vapor_database
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
```

And my testing.Dockerfile

```yaml
FROM swift:5.5

WORKDIR /package

COPY . ./

CMD ["swift", "test", "--enable-test-discovery"]
```

Comment: Is this a docker or a swift question? Also, seems you're also asking multiple questions.

Comment: Regarding the container not being deleted, you can always clean up the container after execution - https://serverfault.com/questions/750175/docker-compose-option-to-automaticaly-remove-container-after-run-in-docker-comp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue that stands out to me is that your revert methods don't seem to actually be deleting the data in the database or removing the table.

I have similar tests that use the revert functionality within Vapor and the migrations look like the following:

```
public struct ListV1: Migration {

    public func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema("Lists")
            .id()
            .field("listId", .int, .required, .custom("UNIQUE"))
            .field("listString", .string, .required)
            .field("createdAt", .datetime)
            .field("updatedAt", .datetime)
            .create()
    }

    public func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        return database.schema("Lists").delete()
    }
}
```

Changing your revert function to use `.delete()` (shown below) may resolve your issue:

```
struct AddressModelMigration_v1_0_0: Migration {

  ...

  func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
    database
      .schema(AddressModel.schema)
      .delete()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just put your App class in a var of your tests representing the *sut* (system under test) and override your test's `setup()` and `tearDown()` methods?

As in:

```
final class AppTests: XCTestCase {
    var sut: Application!
    override setup() {
        super.setup()
        
        sut = Application(.testing)
    }

    override tearDown() {
        sut.shutdown()
        sut = nil
        
        super.tearDown()
    }

    // MARK: - Given

    // MARK: - When
    func whenMigrationsAreSet() async throws {
         sut.migrations.add(UserModelMigration_v1_0_0())
         sut.migrations.add(AddressModelMigration_v1_0_0())
         sut.migrations.add(CompanyModelMigration_v1_0_0())
         try await app.autoRevert()
         try await app.autoMigrate()
    } 
    
    // MARK: - Tests
    func testSignUpRoute_whenUserDoesNotExist_thenUserSignUpAndHTTPStatusIsOk() async throws {
        try await whenMigrationsAreSet()
        
        let headers = [
           "email": "foo@email.com",
           "password": "fooEncrypted",
        ]
        
        let requestExpectation = expectation("request completed")
        let responseExpectation = expectation("got response")
        var result: HTTPStatus?
        try sut.test(.POST, "users/signup") { request in 
             try request.content.encode(headers)
             requestExpectation.fullfill()
        } afterResponse { response in 
             result = response.status
             responseExpectation.fullfill()
        }

        wait(for: [requestExpectation, responseExpectation], timeout: 0.5, enforceOrder: true)
        XCTAssertEqual(result, .ok)
    }

}
```

Anyway I've also added expectations to your test since it seems it was doing some async work with completions in the old fashion.

Comment: App is already in setUp and tearDown. I put them in the test method to simplify the code in StackOverflow, but it works the same. The code you provided is not tested on your side, otherwise, you would have noticed that it doesn’t work for many reasons. Please, make sure that the test passes first before posting your answer.

Comment: So to be clear, what's your request? We have to provide you with a test that passes without knowing what it tests, or your problem is in regards on "how do I write a tests which resets the SUT state after it has finished"? The code you provided seems to have an assertion which outlives the scope of the test, cause such assertion is put into a closure that probably you were not awaiting for.

Comment: As mentioned, I want to clear all the data in my Docker container after each unit test.

Comment: Then you want to run the code that clears the database entries in your Docker container in `tearDown()`. Or you could mock such service so it uses memory storage instead of persisted storage and use that mock only in your tests.
For example to test `CoreData` a common approach is to create its stack as memory based in tests. 
Anyway without more details of your `Application` class is basically impossible to understand which approach is viable, as well as to understand how to eventually revert the database to an empty state.